# Dropdown not updated with new item

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-select and created a component  “SelectControl”. Now I have an array of 2 items used in Options. I am trying to add new item (add 3rd item) in array on a checkbox checked but on UI in dropdown it shows only previous 2 items. In my Component “componentWillRecieveProps” calls and get 3 items and also render method returns 3 items in options. But on UI there are 2 items shown and when I select any item from these 2 items. Then 3rd item appears.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

class SelectControl extends Component {
  // initial state
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      "selectedOption": props.defaultVal,
      OtherInput: false,
      Options: props.options,
      OtherVal: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var found = false;
    if (this.state.selectedOption) {
      if (this.props.multi == true) {
        this.state.selectedOption.find(function (element) {
          if (element.label == "Other") {
            found = true;
          }
        });
      } else {
        found = (this.state.selectedOption.label == "Other");
      }
      if (found == true) {
        this.setState({ OtherInput: true, OtherVal: this.props.otherOptionVal });
        this.props.handleChange("otherOption" + this.props.id, this.props.otherOptionVal);
      } else {
        this.setState({ OtherInput: false });
      }
      this.props.handleChange(this.props.id, this.state.selectedOption);
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.from == "Settings") {
      this.setState({
        Options:
          nextProps.options, OtherVal: nextProps.otherOptionVal
      });
    }
  }

  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ "selectedOption": selectedOption });
    var found = false;
    if (selectedOption) {
      if (this.props.multi == true) {
        selectedOption.find(function (element) {
          if (element.label == "Other") {
            found = true;
          }
        });
      } else if (selectedOption) {
        found = (selectedOption.label == "Other");
      }
      if (found == true) {
        this.setState({ OtherInput: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ OtherInput: false });
      }
    }

    if (this.props.handleChange) {
      this.props.handleChange(this.props.id, selectedOption);
    }
  };

  handleOtherInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({ OtherVal: e.target.value });
    this.props.handleChange("otherOption" + this.props.id, e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const Options = this.state.Options;
    return (
      <div className="field-input-time">
        {this.props.title && <label>{this.props.title}</label>}
        <Select
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder && (this.props.placeholder)}
          id={this.props.id}
          name={this.props.name}
          value={this.state.selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          isMulti={this.props.multi ? this.props.multi : false}
          options={this.state.Options}
        />
        <span id={"error" + this.props.id} className="err-msg">This question is required</span>
        {this.state.OtherInput && <div><input type="text" value={this.state.OtherVal} placeholder="Specify Other.." id={"otherOption" + this.props.id} onChange={e => this.handleOtherInput(e)} />
          <span id={"errorotherOption" + this.props.id} className="err-msg">
            Please Specify Other
  </span></div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SelectControl;
```

Comment: Can you add how you are calling `<SelectControl/>` component with correct props and providing a verifiable code maybe with [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) would greatly help to easily reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi can you post your parent component then we may get an idea where you did mistake

Comment: <SelectControl from="Settings" name="dropdown" options={this.state.dropdownOptionArray} value={this.state.SelectedOption}  id={this.props.item.key} placeholder={this.state.placeholderVal} multi={this.state.moreThanOneAnswer} handleChange={this.handleSelectChange} />

Comment: dropdownOptionArray: [ { value: "Choice 1", label: "Choice 1" },{ value: "Choice 2", label: "Choice 2" }], Now I add { value: "Other", label: "Other" } but its not reflect on UI

Comment: But when handleChange event fires it is working means updated item showing

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to point out that using componentWillReceiveProps to duplicate data coming from another state can lead to *source of truth duplication*. [Facebook itself advise to use it sparingly](https://it.reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state)

In this case, why you don't user directly option coming from props ?

```
<Select
  placeholder={this.props.placeholder && (this.props.placeholder)}
  id={this.props.id}
  name={this.props.name}
  value={this.state.selectedOption}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  isMulti={this.props.multi ? this.props.multi : false}
  options={this.props.options}
/>
```

Comment: Raguzzini <SelectControl from="Settings" name="dropdown" options={this.state.dropdownOptionArray} value={this.state.SelectedOption} id={this.props.item.key} placeholder={this.state.placeholderVal} multi={this.state.moreThanOneAnswer} handleChange={this.handleSelectChange} />
This is componrent i used

Comment: dropdownOptionArray: [ { value: "Choice 1", label: "Choice 1" },{ value: "Choice 2", label: "Choice 2" }], Now I add { value: "Other", label: "Other" } but its not reflect on UI

Comment: have you tried (like in my snippet) `options={this.props.options}` ?

Comment: Raguzzini I have tried  options={this.props.options} also but not working

Comment: But when handleChange event fires it is working means updated item showing

Comment: Can you post a complete snippet reproducing the issue on stackblitz ?

Comment: @Raguzzini I have resolved the issue with two ways first using slice() and Second using concat([]). but don't know how these functions are working could you please explain me

Comment: Check this @Raguzzini 1. var option = { value: "Other", label: "Other" };var options = this.state.dropdownOptionArray.slice();options.push(option);
2. var option = { value: "Other", label: "Other" };var options = this.state.dropdownOptionArray;options.push(option); options = options.concat([]);